# Object exists in the HTML but I'm unable to select it

Tags: java, html, dom, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm writing a **scraper**. When I use inspect element in chrome I see the following:

[image: code visible in chrome inspect element]

but when I run my code `Elements data = doc.select("div.item-header");` and I print the object **data** I see that the object has the following chunk of html in it:

```
<div class="item-header"> 
 <h1 class="text size-20">Snake print bell sleeves top</h1> 
 <div class="text size-12 muted brandname ma_top5">
       <!-- data here is irrelevant --> 
 </div> 
</div>
```

So, what I can't figure out is, why does my code get a different html than that visible in chrome's inspect element? What am I missing here?

I'm using java, the library is Jsoup. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that the HTML you are trying to scrape has more than one `div` with the class `item-header`?

Comment: It's also possible that the data is loaded after the DOM is loaded (ajax?).

Comment: it may possible that your site has code to muted Html while Chrom is open, hence you are getting different result   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798748/find-out-whether-chrome-console-is-open

Comment: FYI it's __scraper__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scrape__) not scrapper. A scrapper is someone who throws things away, i.e. pretty much the opposite of what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Websites consist of HTML and JavaScript code. Often that JavaScript is executed when the page is loaded and it's possible that the source of a page is modified or some additional content is loaded by asynchronous AJAX calls. Jsoup can't parse Javascript so it can only parse the original HTML document.
Don't use Chrome's `Inspect` option as it presents HTML after possible transformations. Use `View source` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>). This  way you'll see original HTML source unmodified by JavaScript (you can also try reloading the page with JavaScript disabled). And that original source is what gets downloaded and parsed by Jsoup.
If that's the case and you really want to parse the data that's loaded by JavaScript try to observe `XHR` requests in Chrome's `Network` tab. You can check this answer to see what I mean: [How to Load Entire Contents of HTML - Jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54511718/how-to-load-entire-contents-of-html-jsoup/54513505#54513505)

Comment: This seems to be the case. And that link helps.
Thanks.