# Get full HTML using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I'am scraping web-page using Jsoup library by selecting class attributes which contains "nav" string in them.

This is the code which fetch HTML of the site:

```
var bodyString = Jsoup.connect(url)
                .ignoreContentType(true)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
                .timeout(12000)
                .followRedirects(true)
                .execute()
                .body();
```

Example of Html which is selected by Jsoup CSS selector:
[image]

Yet in browser same website Html looks like this:
[image]

As you can see ul element with id="varPreviewMenu" contains li elements which HTML retrieved by Jsoup does not contains.

How can I get those elements?

Comment: The first part of this answer applies to your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54505676/jsoup-hidden-div-class/54507805#54507805

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390741/jsoup-get-dynamically-generated-html/22400976#22400976

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the elements you see are dynamically added to the DOM by some JavaScript code. That means they are not available in the body of the request when you use Jsoup.